# swiftmailer fetch multiple emails from mysql database seperated by comma

Tags: php, email

i have a table in my database where i have msg to send by email

here is my code

```
    <?php
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ex_smartcard");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$query = mysqli_query($con,"Select autosend.to,
  autosend.cc,
  autosend.bcc,
  autosend.subject,
  autosend.msg,
  autosend.start,
  autosend.expiry,
  autosend.freq,
  autosend.timestamp
From autosend
Where autosend.start <= CurDate() And autosend.expiry >= CurDate() And
  autosend.freq = 3");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))

{

$to = $row['to'];
$cc = $row['cc'];
$subject = $row['subject'];
$emailBody="";
$emailBody .= $row['msg'];




// Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('192.168.0.1', 25)
  ->setUsername('smartcard@example.com')
  ->setPassword('123456')
  ;

/*
You could alternatively use a different transport such as Sendmail or Mail:

// Sendmail
$transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');

// Mail
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
*/

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

  // Give the message a subject
  ->setSubject($subject)

  // Set the From address with an associative array
  ->setFrom(array('smartcard@lotus.edu.in' => 'Lotus Reminder'))

  // Set the To addresses with an associative array
  ->setTo(array($to))

  // Using setCc() to set all recipients in one go
  ->setCc(array($cc))


  // Give it a body
  ->setBody($emailBody)



  ;

$headers = $message->getHeaders();
// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
printf("Sent %d messages\n", $result);
echo $cc;

}

?>
```

$to = email1@example.com
$cc = email2@example.com, email3@example.com

i am receiving this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_RfcComplianceException' with message 'Address in mailbox given [email1@example.com, email2@example.com] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\Swift\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php:352 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\Swift\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php(264): Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader->_assertValidAddress('ishan@lotus.edu...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\Swift\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php(108): Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader->normalizeMailboxes(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\Swift\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php(65): Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader->setNameAddresses(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\Swift\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\SimpleHeaderFactory.php(60): Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader->setFieldBodyModel(Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\Swift\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\SimpleHeaderSet.php(70): Swift_Mime_SimpleHeaderFactory->createMailboxHeader('Cc', A in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\Swift\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\MailboxHeader.php on line 352
```

Tell me how to send them i am having many mails in cc column seperated with comma should i change the format of mails in mysql or change in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried passing multiple values as an array, e.g.:

```
$cc = array('email1@example.com', 'email2@example.com');
```

See the [Syntax for Addresses](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#adding-recipients-to-your-message) subsection of the docs.

If that works, and you're looking to turn a comma-separated string you get from a database into an array, the [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function should help.

EDIT:

Maybe something like:

```
$cc = array_map('trim', explode(',', $row['cc']));
```

Where explode splits the string into an array over the commas and the `array_map()` function applies the `trim()` function to each of the array's elements, removing any remaining whitespace on either end.

Comment: yes it is working but i want emails from mysql database pls tell me changes in code.....

Comment: @ShiveshJaiswal, see my edit for a general idea of how you could approach it.

Answer (score 0):

cc must be passed in valid array form

```
$array = array("email1@example.com", "email2@example.com");
$subject = "hrere";
$message = new Swift_Message($subject);
$message->setCc($array);
```

Comment: if i specify mails here its working but how to get it from mysql

Comment: Something like this should work, while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ $array[] = $row['cc']; } now just pass this array to setCc function